# Why did Christopher abandon everything and go wild in "Into the Wild"?

Tags: plot-explanation, into-the-wild

There's a lot of different reasons all over the internet and even some insight from his real-life sister, but I recall Christopher mentioning somewhere in the middle of *Into the Wild* (2007):

- It was hinted all over the first part, but never revealed fully until the middle (approximately).
- It was some "secret" concerning his family and/or his sister.
- He didn't know it at first, but the learned this *secret* and it was partly responsible for his departure.
- *It's not likely to be abuse from his father, as his real-life sister states* (though I'm not so sure here).

All in all, I remember that clearly mentioned in the film, but I can't just find that reason.

Comment: @Jenayah I'm not really sure if the *plot-explanation* is appropriate here since I believe it is not that movie *revolves around that*, it is more as a recurring theme and not even the single reason for his trip

Comment: I'd say as it's part of the plot (well, maybe not the "whole" reason; but "abandon everything and go into the wild" is _almost_ the title ;) ), so [plot-explanation], but I won't mind at all if you reject the edit, it's your question and your call :)

Comment: @Jenayah "but "abandon everything and go into the wild" is *almost* the title" - well, can't argue with that, let this be, I just wanted to clarify that it isn't something deep and easy to miss, it's just something I can't remember :)

Answer (score 2):

## It was the fact Chris and his sister were bastards.

I did partially rewatch the movie and this is explained at approximately 53rd minute.

Christopher's sister narrates that he found out his father had another son from his [father's] first wife to whom he still was officially married **after** Chris was born. Thus, Chris and his sister realized they were bastards.

> This fact suddenly re-defined Chris and me as bastard children. Dad's arrogance made him conveniently oblivious to the pain he caused. And Mom, in the shame and
>   embarrassment of a young mistress, became his accomplice in deceit.
>
> <sub>Source: [Into the Wild script](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/a3/into-the-wild-script-transcript.html)</sub>

Comment: That, at the violence in the family. There's a scene in which is parents get into an argument about cancelling Christmas, and he starts beating her. Both Chris and his sister watch the scene.